# Large equation goes out of margin

Tags: equations

### Equation is going out of margin (page)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb} 
\usepackage{icomma} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{theorem} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{commath} 
\usepackage{bm} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}\label{Equation 1}
Y\left ( \delta_0,A,\delta_1,\delta_3,T_{min}  \right )=
(A_1*(\delta_0*sin(\delta_0) + \delta_0 *sin(\delta_1) + w*cos(\delta_3)*1i)) +
 (A*exp(-T_{min}*\delta_0)*(sin(T_{min}*w) + cos(T_{min}*w)*1i)*
(\delta_0*cos(\phi - T_{min}*\delta_0) + w*cos(\phi - T_{min}*\delta_0)*1i +
 \omega_0*sin(\phi - T_{min}*\omega_0))*1i))/
(\delta_0^2 + \delta_1*w*2i - w_1^2 + \delta_0^2)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then you'll need to change this from an `equation` to an `align` construction. LaTeX does not auto break displayed formulas as that is very subjective and thus better left to a human.

Comment: I tried with aligning but it dont give with break

Comment: i  have seen some question regarding this issue. People used \bigg1 but i dont know how to use it

Comment: problem solved. \multline* is used to write a big equation.

Comment: You might also be interested in `\split`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I interpreted correctly your formula, but in addition of the `multline` environment, I nested it in the `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath`, which uses locally the `fleqn` option from `amsmath`, to ensure the multline starts at the left margin. Next, I used  `\splitfrac` from `mathtools` (in medsize), and removed the `*` symbols, which are not used in maths for multiplication, to save space – I just left the `*1i`, because I have idea what they correspond to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{theorem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{multline}\label{Equation 2}
Y( \delta_0,A,\delta_1,\delta_3,T_{\min} )= \Bigl(A_1\bigl(\delta_0\sin(\delta_0) + \delta_0\sin(\delta_1) + w\cos(\delta_3)*1i\bigr)\Bigr) + \\
 + \frac{\medmath{\splitfrac{%
\Bigl (A\exp(-T_{\min} \delta_0) \bigl(\sin(T_{\min} w) + \cos(T_{\min} w)*1i\bigr)
\bigl(\delta_0\cos(\phi - T_{\min}\delta_0)}{{} + w\cos(\phi - T_{\min} \delta_0)*1i +
 \omega_0\sin(\phi - T_{\min}\omega_0)\bigr)*1i \Bigr)}}}
{(\delta_0^2 + \delta_1 w2i - w_1^{2} + \delta_0^2)\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
\end{multline}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nit-picking: the plus sign at the end of the first line should instead be at the beginning of the second line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton:  I know –  it is actually in both lines. I thought it would be clearer, due to the use of `\splitfrac`. The reader knows something  comes afterwards.